# Create new dataframe based on sequential row values

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, rolling-computation, accumulate

I have a dataframe of names and years, with a dummy variable for whether the name occurred in a year or not.

I'm trying to create a dataframe which tell me

- 1. the total number names which appeared in that year, and
- 2. the number of those which appeared in that year but not in the year before.

In the below example, in 2017 there is only one person occurring (Terry) and nothing for the previous year, so both total and new would be 1. In 2018 three people occur but only two are new as Terry occurred in the previous year. If somebody appeared in 2017 and 2019 but not in 2018, they should be classed as new in 2019.

EXAMPLE

```
   Name x2017 x2018 x2019
1 Terry     1     1     0
2   Sam     0     0     1
3   Nic     0     1     1
4 Sarah     0     1     1
```

CODE

```
data.frame(
  Name = c("Terry", "Sam", "Nic", "Sarah"), 
  x2017 = c(1, 0, 0, 0), 
  x2018 = c(1, 0, 1, 1), 
  x2019 = c(0, 1, 1, 1)
  )
```

OUTPUT I'M TRYING TO CREATE

```
  Year Total New
1 2017     1   1
2 2018     3   2
3 2019     3   1
```

I've tried filtering and using row sums, but I feel like there's a function which I don't know of that can do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

1. Reshape to long format using e.g. `tidy::pivot_longer`
2. Group by `Name` and make use of `dplyr::lag` to add an indicator whether a person is new
3. Summarise by year

```r
d <- data.frame(
  Name = c("Terry", "Sam", "Nic", "Sarah"), 
  x2017 = c(1, 0, 0, 0), 
  x2018 = c(1, 0, 1, 1), 
  x2019 = c(0, 1, 1, 1)
) 

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

d %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-Name, names_to = "year") %>% 
  mutate(year = gsub("^x", "", year)) %>%
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  mutate(new = as.numeric(value == 1 & lag(value) == 0),
         new = ifelse(is.na(new), value, new)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise(total = sum(value), new = sum(new))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   year  total   new
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 2017      1     1
#> 2 2018      3     2
#> 3 2019      3     1
```

Comment: this won't give you correct results in many cases.  It checks whether a record is available in just previous year and not in `any of the previous years` Try this on `structure(list(Name = c("Terry", "Sam", "Nic", "Sarah"), x2017 = c(1, 0, 0, 1), x2018 = c(1, 0, 1, 0), x2019 = c(0, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: @AnilGoyal. The OP defined new as *"If somebody appeared in 2017 and 2019 but not in 2018, they should be classed as new in 2019."*. That's why I only checked for the previous year.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks for clarification, I will revise my answer shortly. :)

Answer (score 3):

The  `mutate(new = as.numeric(values == 1 & lag(values) == 0), new = ifelse(is.na(new), values, new)) %>%`part is from stefan
(credits to him, thank you stefan).
The difference is `parse_number`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -Name,
    names_to = "Year", 
    values_to = "values"
  ) %>% 
  mutate(Year = parse_number(Year)) %>% 
  mutate(new = as.numeric(values == 1 & lag(values) == 0),
         new = ifelse(is.na(new), values, new)) %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  summarise(Total = sum(values), New = sum(new))
```

output:

```
   Year Total   New
* <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  2017     1     1
2  2018     3     2
3  2019     3     1
```

Comment: Nice solution. At first I suspected why I can't think of a more concise solution. Apparently there wasn't any about this question lol.

Answer (score 3):

**Updated-02**
I am so sorry as I had to revise my solution, cause I realized that only when a name has occurred in the previous year it is not considered new so you can use also use this for your sample data and the one presented below the page:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)


df %>% 
  summarise(across(2:4, ~ sum(.x))) %>%
  bind_cols() %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "Year", values_to = "Total", 
               names_prefix = "x") %>%
  left_join(df %>% select(2:4) %>% pmap_dfr(~ {x <- c(...); x - lag(x, default = 0)}) %>% 
              summarise(across(everything(), ~ sum(.x == 1))) %>% 
              pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "Year", values_to = "New", 
                           names_prefix = "x"), 
            by = "Year")
 

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Year  Total   New
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2017      1     1
2 2018      3     2
3 2019      3     1
```

Comment: I was happy to see your solution. This gave me now the power to learn `purrr`. Thank you Anoushiravan. Maybe you are interested in this question of mine <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67760424/concatenate-column-names-in-one-column-conditional-on-using-mutate-across-and-c>

Comment: Oh yes I saw it today but was a bit late as some of my prospective solutions had been already posted so I just voted and sit out. Bravo by the way it was a very good question.

Comment: These two questions might also be of interest to you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66833328/using-pmap-to-iterate-over-rows-of-a-tibble
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67049561/using-pmap-with-c-part-2

Answer (score 2):

case-I When records have to be checked in one previous row only.

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(!Name, names_to = 'Year', names_prefix = 'x') %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(value),
            new = list(Name[value == 1]), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  mutate(new = map2_int(new, lag(new), ~ sum(!(.x %in% .y))))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Year  total   new
  <chr> <dbl> <int>
1 2017      1     1
2 2018      3     2
3 2019      3     1
```

---

Case-II when records have to be looked into all previous rows. Using both `map_*` and `accumulate`.  The strategy adopted-

- `pivot_longer` first.  drop `x` from years directly here using `names_prefix` argument
- `group_by` on year then
- calculate total values `n()` and names for that year in a `list`
- mutate `new` using `map2_int` with first argument as that list only, and second argument as `accumulate`d and `lag`ged list .
- `map2_int` thus calculates the total number of `TRUE` in that row.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(!Name, names_to = 'Year', names_prefix = 'x') %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(value),
         new = list(Name[value == 1]), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  mutate(new = map2_int(new, lag(accumulate(new, union, .init = first(new))[-1]), ~ sum(!(.x %in% .y))))

#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   Year  total   new
#>   <chr> <int> <int>
#> 1 2017      1     1
#> 2 2018      3     2
#> 3 2019      3     1
```